# How do $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z^+$ have the same cardinality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

The book "First Course in Abstract Algebra" by John Fraleigh says that  $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z^+$ have the same cardinality.

He defines the pairing like this

1 <-> 0
2 <-> -1
3 <-> 1
4 <-> -2
5 <-> 2
6 <-> -3

and so on.

How exactly is this the same cardinality? Is he using the fact that both are infinite sets to say that they have the same cardinality? Does that mean that all infinite sets have the same cardinality?

Comment: "The same cardinality" has a precise definition. Maybe you should read that. It would be a lot easier to understand what's going on if you do. I have good memories of Fraleigh; there ought to be a definition somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to focus on the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of *having the same cardinality*.
By definition, two sets $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if there exists a function $f: A \to B$ which is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) (see the links for more info).

Then, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^+$ have the same cardinality since there exists a bijection between them. The one you cited, it is just a *possible bijection* between many, which can be characterized as follows:

\begin{align*}
& f: \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z},\\
f(x) = & \ 
\begin{cases}
 \frac{x-1}{2} & \text{ if $x$ is odd;} \\
- \frac{x}{2} & \text{ if $x$ is even.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Please choose best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two sets $A,B$ have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection $f : A \to B$.

This is the case here where the pairing is a way to describe the bijection $f : \mathbb Z^+ \to \mathbb Z$:

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
\frac{n-1}{2} & \text{ if n is odd}\\
- \frac{n}{2} & \text{ if n is even}
\end{cases}$$

Regarding your second question, the answer is negative. Not all sets have the same cardinality. One can prove that for a set $A$ the power set $\mathcal P(A)$ doesn't have the same cardinality than $A$. You can find an injection from $A$ into $\mathcal P(A)$ but the converse is not possible.

For example the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is greater than the one of $\mathbb N$.